# CSS linear gradient to XAML

Tags: css, xaml, linear-gradients

What is the most natural conversion of this bit of CSS to WPF XAML?

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #F25597 20%, #7C68E3 50%, #014FA4 80%);
```

First attempt - but it does not look exactly like in the browser:

```
<LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                     StartPoint="0.25,0" EndPoint="0.75,1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#F25597" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#7C68E3" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#014FA4" Offset="1"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

There doesn't appear to be a rotation angle option in XAML, so this formulation is based on two endpoints of a line.

Update: also found these CSS properties:

```
.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #F25597 20%, #7C68E3 50%, #014FA4 80%);
    background-size: 150%;
    background-position: 50%;
}
```

How it looks in HTML/CSS:

[image: HTML/CSS rendering]

Answer (score 0):

After much more tweaking, additional transformations around origo seems to solve the discrepancy:

```
<LinearGradientBrush MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" 
                     StartPoint="0,1" EndPoint="0,0">
    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" Angle="110"/>
            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
            <TranslateTransform Y="0.5"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStopCollection>
            <GradientStop Color="#F25597" Offset="0.2"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#7C68E3" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#014FA4" Offset="0.8"/>
        </GradientStopCollection>
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

From the XAML editor in Visual Studio:

[image: XAML-rendered gradient]